# Fitting a Flattened Gaussian model to the given data

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a very complicated (Flattened Gaussian) model to a data I have obtained.
[Image for flattened Gaussian formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8gfe.png)
(variable fc in my code here represents vo, central frequency.)

I have written the code in python using from scipy.optimize import curve_fit. 
It is unable to optimize my equation and always gives the same answers for the parameters.
Link to the data file: https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/795968/my-file.dat

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x    = np.loadtxt("my-file.dat")[:,0]
yres = np.loadtxt("my-file.dat")[:,1]
def flatgauss(x, A,fc,t,w):
    B= ((4*(x-fc)**2)/ w**2 ) * np.log((-1/t)*np.log((1+ np.exp(-t))/2))
    return -A*( (1-np.exp(-t*np.exp(B)))/ (1-np.exp(-t)) )
popt, pcov = curve_fit(flatgauss, x, yres)
print ("fitted parameters:", popt)
```

This is what I get:
OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  category=OptimizeWarning)
fitted parameters: [1. 1. 1. 1.]

Please help me with fitting this using either scipy or any other module that you think is good. (like emcee)

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data file?

Comment: Yes, I have now edited the post to include a link to the data file. Here it is: <https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/795968/my-file.dat>

Comment: I do not want to accept their terms of service or give them my email address, both required for that download link.

Comment: Try emailing to me at zunzun@zunzun.com

Comment: Ok here is another link in which you need not accept any terms or need to provide an email id. <http://www.mediafire.com/file/7puj3hanac8aklr/my-file.dat/file>

Comment: Got it, nvestigating now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default initial parameter estimates for scipy's curve_fit routine are all 1.0, and since no improvement on those estimates could be made they were returned giving "fitted parameters: [1. 1. 1. 1.]". If you look at a scatterplot of the data as shown below, the posted data does not lie on a flattened Gaussian peak - or any other preak equation - so curve_fit fails on the equation you used.

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How about the following data file which is exactly formed from the flattened gaussian equation? I still get the same answer:

Comment: This again means that you have not given good initial parameter estimates to scipy's curve_fit routine, as I discussed in my answer.

Comment: But I didn't give any initial values at all. And the bounds are also not specified

Comment: I quote from my answer: "The default initial parameter estimates for scipy's curve_fit routine are all 1.0".

Comment: Thank you, I have now given some appropriate initial values and have achieved the fit